# Sumif Excel Function Error

Tags: excel, sumifs

I'm trying to calculate the days that an employee had an overtime; but the function keeps give an error function. 
I tried after searching use (;) instead of (,); but still keep getting the error.

**The function:**

```
=SUMIFS(LeaveTracker[Days],LeaveTracker[Employee Name],valSelEmployee,WEEKDAY(LeaveTracker[Start Date]),">5",WEEKDAY(LeaveTracker[End Date]),">5",LeaveTracker[Type of Leave],'Leave Types'!B8)
```

**The Error message:**
The formula you typed contains an error.

Comment: `criteria_range` arguments need to be `ranges`.  You have two which are not:  `WEEKDAY(LeaveTracker[Start Date])` does not return a `range`.  It returns an array of weekday numbers.  Hence your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment, `criteria_range` arguments need to be ranges. You have two which are not: `WEEKDAY(LeaveTracker[Start Date])` and `WEEKDAY(LeaveTracker[End Date])` do not return a range. They returns an array of weekday numbers. Hence your error.

You could add two helper columns containing just the Weekday number referenced to start and end date, and then use those columns for the `criteria_range` in place of what you have.

So add a column named `StartWeekDay` with the formula:  `=WEEKDAY([@[Start Date]])`
and similarly add a column named `EndWeekDay`

Then you can use `SUMIFS`:

```
=SUMIFS(LeaveTracker[Days],LeaveTracker[Employee Name],valSelEmployee,(LeaveTracker[StartWeekDay]),">5",(LeaveTracker[EndWeekDay]),">5",LeaveTracker[Type of Leave],'Leave Types'!B8)
```

Or you can use the `SUMPRODUCT` function, which can perform that logic on your existing data with no need for helper columns.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LeaveTracker[Days]*(LeaveTracker[Employee Name]=valSelEmployee)*(WEEKDAY(LeaveTracker[Start Date])>5)*(WEEKDAY(LeaveTracker[End Date])>5)*(LeaveTracker[Type of Leave]='Leave Types'!B8))
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for SUMIFS is :

```
SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2], ...)
```

If:

LeaveTracker[Days] is the sum_range and

LeaveTracker[Employee Name] is the criteria_range

what is valSelEmployee?

According to the syntax, it should be the first criteria. Does it contain the Employee name to search? If so, it should have an operator (=, > etc)

Comment: If I'll put the = operator, it'll consider the valSelEmployee as a whole string or text.

Comment: It gives all the right values but there is no final result

Comment: You will need to put an '=' sign in on 'Leave Types'!B8 too as this is also a criteria

Comment: All the values correct, the final result is still gives {...}

Comment: Can you put an anonymous version of the sheet on here and I'll look properly tomorrow.

Comment: If your criteria is to be an `=`, there is no need for the `=` operator. It will be understood.  If you do want to use it, you need to quote it and concatenate it with the variable or reference.